# Woocommerce mail funtion returning NULL even mail is sent

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to send mail in wordpress using

```
$subject = 'WC Send Mail Test';

// load the mailer
$mailer = WC()->mailer();
$send = $mailer->send( get_option( 'admin_email' ), $subject, $mailer->wrap_message( $subject, 'a test message' ), '', '' );
if($send){
 echo "Sent";
}else{
 echo "Not sent";
}
```

This function works fine but i'm not able to track mail is sent or not.
$send is always NULL

Above code is taken from http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/10/2-3-emails/

Comment: What do you mean you can't track it? Where are you trying to track this?

Comment: as simple as that code, I can assure you that should return true... if the mail was sent.. there's no way that could return a null cause it can only return true or false...

Comment: @ShravanShrama Take off the last two parameters. This should now return `true` in your case.

Comment: @Phorce not working..

Comment: Is `get_option( 'admin_email' )` set?

Comment: @mevius mail is sent to admin but i just want to execute some code if mail is sent but unfortunately $send giving me NULL

Comment: is your code really look like this? Seriously, function `send` will only return true or false... it is using [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Return) and will only return value of bool type..

Comment: `echo "Sent".` should be `echo "Sent";`

Comment: @Reigel my code as it is. I think its a WooCommerce issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution. I'm trying to digging out the woocommerce code and find the woocommerce use this file to send email

**woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php**

Around line no. 214 I found the send method.

I have change the code

```
$email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
```

to

```
$return = $email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
return $return;
```

---

```
                           **OR**
```

Since changing the wordpress core functionality is a bad habit so i get a proper way to override the wordpress core functionality.

I have just created a directory structure inside the child-theme like

**woocommerce/includes**

Here you have to create a file named **class-wc-emails.php** and paste your edited file code here.

Please don't go for **OR** section this is not working for me.

Comment: Can this be seen as a bug in the Woocommerce code? If so, please report it to them so they can fix it for everyone. Also remember that if you update Woocommerce, this change will be undone.

Comment: @Forza I think so. I should ask the woocommerce developer for this.

Comment: @Reigel are you talking about https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php. I agree with you they handled return here. But look here https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-emails.php around line no 214. my function sending emails from here and no return is handle here.

Comment: changing a core is bad habit... can you try this last suggestion? here it is... try changing your `$mailer = WC()->mailer();` to `$mailer = WC_Email();`. If this won't work then yes, changing the core it is... ;)

Comment: @Reigel I know it's a bad habit, but i'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function WC_Email() while using your suggestion.

Comment: I see... you need to include the file `class-wc-email.php` ... anyway, `send` function is just using `wp_mail` internally. so to get away of editing the core, you can either use `wp_mail` or `WC_Email`. good luck ;)

Comment: I think i have one more option. we can override core function in wordpress  child theme. may i ?

Answer (score 0):

You should var_dump $send, and see whats returned. Else why dont you try using the wordpress native mail function?

```
$multiple_recipients = array(
    'recipient1@example.com',
    'recipient2@foo.example.com'
);
$subj = 'The email subject';
$body = 'This is the body of the email';
if(wp_mail( $multiple_recipients, $subj, $body )){
 // Mail Sent Successfully
}else{
 // Mail not sent
}
```

Comment: Actually my clients wants each email format should be same. Since We are using woocommerce to our app, so we decided to that email format would be same as woocommerce order email format, thats why i'm using woocommerce mail function.

Comment: I guess you found the answer but the best way to standardise all your emails is to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-template/. I really like this plugin and usually use it on the whole website, so all the emails sent from wordpress + woocommerce follow the same template.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my requirement does't fit for this.